# How can I open an Excel file and modify it in Mathematica?

Tags: import, files-and-directories

I wanted to ask how can I view an Excel file from a *Mathematica* notebook and modify it.

I have seen a similar question, [Open Excel file with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4594), but the answer involves .NET. Is there any other way to open an Excel file and modify it?

Comment: You could `Import[]` a spreadsheet, but I don't believe there's a native way to have a spreadsheet interface within *Mathematica*...

Comment: @J.M. well there is `TableView` ...

Comment: @J.M.: I dont want to import the values because I want that end user can open the Excel file and change its values if needed and then use it in application.

Comment: @Mr.Wiz, undocumented, I see... :)

Comment: Then I don't quite understand why you want to use *Mathematica* to open Excel files... something about "use the proper tool for the job"?

Comment: @J.M. actually the undocumented `TableView` looks very spreadsheet-like.

Comment: @Verbeia: yeah, I tried it out after Wizard brought it up. Looks like a good start, but its being undocumented is rather inconvenient...

Comment: @J.M.: I am building an application in mathematica and it is using some large values. I wanted to give the control to users to change those values.

Comment: Then I suppose `TableView[Import["file.xls"]]` or something like it would be useful?

Comment: To visualize/edit a spreadsheet in Mathematica: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3868/how-to-visualize-edit-a-big-matrix-as-a-table/3870#3870

Answer (score 8):

Amending the file directly would indeed require something like .Net.
If you were willing to consider an import-export roundtrip but with a spreadsheet like interface in Mathematica, then something like this might work:

```
rawdata = (Import["myspreadsheet.xlsx"][[2]]);
 (* where 2 is the number of the worksheet you want to use *)
newdata = TableView[rawdata]
```

Now, change the data cells you want to change and then type <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> when the cursor is in that `TableView`.

Then in another cell, evaluate:

```
newnewdata = %[[1]]
```

This will give you an expression with the list of changed data, stripped of the enclosing `TableView` `Head`.

You can then `Export` that changed expression back to Excel if that is what you wish.

Comment: `TableView` has some useful column sorting capabilities.

Comment: @Verbeia: Thanks...but I have tried it in another way. I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
Row[{
 Button["Browse", (g = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]; SystemOpen[g]), Method -> "Queued"],    
 Button["Import", y = Import[g, "Data"]]}]
```

I have made two `Buttons`, one for browsing the`Excel file` and other `imports` it.