# Excel-like UI in Mathematica

Tags: notebooks, interface

This is NOT about importing/exporting Excel data to/from Mathematica.

This is purely a UI question.

The Mathematica notebook interface is very "linear" — I type in an input cell and *Mathematica* produces an output cell. Is it possible to implement something like an Excel interface for *Mathematica*?

For example, if I have:

- cell `a1 = "x+y"`
- cell `b1 = "x-y"`
- cell `c1 = "= a1^2 + b1^2"`

Then, *Mathematica* puts "2(x^2+y^2)" into `c1`. If I modify `a1` to say `"3"`, *Mathematica* puts `"(x-y)^2 + 9"` into `c1`.

Comment: To whomever voted to close: how is this *not a real question*?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3868/5

Comment: @rm-rf I don't know; that seems to be only about entering values, rather than more traditional spreadsheet interactions.  I think this is an interesting extension.

Comment: Wolfram talked about this on the 2009 or 2010 WTC. Since then, it has been on my wish list for M9 (but my list is very big...). It would definitely allow for a better first contact with Mathematica, since everybody knows the Excel interface; Excel on steroids, with symbolic computation inside cells!

Answer (score 8):

Here's a very basic start:

```
a1 = x + y;
b1 = x - y;
{{InputField[Dynamic[a1]], InputField[Dynamic[b1]], 
   InputField[Dynamic[a1^2 + b1^2]]}} // TableView
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: hmm; I really like how the "TableView" "InputField" and "Dynamic" just "composes together" in creating this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't TableView something which isn't "officially" a part of Mathematica, in the sense that it's not documented and might very well change or be dropped completely in newer versions?

Comment: @jVincent: what is the proposed replacement?

Comment: @user1647794 Well TableView isn't doing anything with respect to the functionality you asked for, so you could use Grid, instead, or remove one level of parenthesis and use Row or Column.

Comment: @jVincent That is correct.  It seemed appropriate to give it a spreadsheet feel.  This answer is far from complete but I hope it inspires someone to post a better one.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think this direction is quite well covered [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3868/how-to-visualize-edit-a-big-matrix-as-a-table) :)

Comment: Could use `TableForm[{{InputField[Dynamic[a1]], InputField[Dynamic[b1]], 
   InputField[Dynamic[a1^2 + b1^2]]}}, TableHeadings -> Automatic]` perhaps?