# Excel column label from integer

Tags: excel

I would like to create a function in *Mathematica*, which returns the equivalent Excel column label (e.g.,  A, Z, AA, AZ, and so on) given a column number.

I think it can be done with `IntegerString[10,26]`, but this representation set of this chars is 0 to 9 and then a to z.
However, Excel uses only A to Z.

How can this be done?

Comment: To clarify: if, say, the function is named `spreadsheetColumn[]`, then `spreadsheetColumn[27]` should return `"AA"`?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/2634427/353410 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/181596/353410

Comment: @J. M., yes, could this be right in this way? myexcelcol = {Characters[IntegerString[ #, 26]] /. 
     {"0" -> A, "1" -> B, "2" -> C, "3" -> D, "4" -> E, "5" -> F, 
      "6" -> G, "7" -> H, "8" -> I, "9" -> J, "a" -> K, "b" -> L, 
      "c" -> M, "d" -> N, "e" -> O, "f" -> P, "g" -> Q, "h" -> R, 
      "i" -> S, "j" -> T, "k" -> U, "l" -> V, "m" -> W, "n" -> X, 
      "o" -> Y, "p" -> Z}} &;

Comment: It does not work properly. What do I wront. @belisarius I need this fnc in Mathematica, and I can not find it in your ref

Comment: the inverse fnc of the wanted fnc is:at@MyExcelStartPos  where [Code] (*Transformation from Excel "A1" notation to indexes*)
at = {FromDigits@
     ToExpression@Flatten[StringCases[Characters[#], _?DigitQ], 1], 
    FromDigits[
     Flatten[ToCharacterCode /@ 
        StringCases[Characters[#], _?UpperCaseQ] - 
       First@ToCharacterCode["A"] + 1, 2], 
     Length@CharacterRange["A", "Z"]]} &; [/Code]

Comment: The difficulty in Excel column naming is the lack of a zero. Counting starts at 'a' (1),  goes to 'z' (26), then to 'aa' (27). In a normal base 26 system with 26 symbols, the first one ('a' in this case) would have value 0 and the last one ('z') 25. 'ba', the smallest two digit number, would then be 26, and 'baa', the smallest three digit number, 1* 26^2 + 0*26^1 + 0*26^0 = 676. Unfortunately, in Excel the smallest two-digit number is 'aa' which means that 'a' in a way acts as both a zero and a one.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Thanks very much for this explanation, now it is clear that it can not be done easily with INtergerDigits.

Comment: Another link of potential interest: [matlab implementation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7765-fillgrid/content/nn2an.m)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, well, I only needed the inverse function so far and have implemented it as:

```
FromExcelCol[col_String] := FromDigits[ToCharacterCode[col] - 64, 26]
```

It runs fine because FromDigits does not complain about characters larger than base-1.

However, the other way round seems to be more tricky. The leading digit runs from 0 to 26 (1 to 27 if you want -> base 27), but only as long as it is leading. Then it runs as a trailing digit from 1 to 26.

I have not found an elegant, non-iterative solution so far. I was hesitating to paste my (ugly but working) piece of code, but maybe it encourages others to look for a nice solution. :)

```
ToExcelCol[n_Integer] := Module[{subtract, num, base},

  subtract = Accumulate[Power[26, #] & /@ (Range[7] - 1)];
  base = Position[subtract, x_ /; x > n, {1}, 1][[1, 1]] - 1; (*find largest number which is <= base ... I think there are better alg. for this but I don't have them at hand, sorry*)
  num = n - subtract[[base]];

  StringJoin@PadLeft[FromCharacterCode /@ (IntegerDigits[num, 26] + 65), base, "A"]
  ]
```

Basically, what you have to do and what this function does, is subtract 26^0 if n > 26^0, then subtract 26^1 if n > 26^1+26^0 and so on. Finally pad the result to x digits with the largest 26^x+26^(x-1)+....

I have tried but I could not make a satisfying solution, so I kindly invite you to improve this piece of code. I still find that it is too iterating (with the lookup table generated in the first step). I have also thought of treating part of the number as base 27 and the other part as base 26, but well... not tonight anymore. :)

**EDIT:**
Jacob just figured out what I was looking for: You can determine the number of digits in the final column name with `Log[26, 25 (n + 1)]`. So, here is the simplified version:

```
ToExcelCol2[n_Integer] := Module[{num, base},
  base = Floor[Log[26, 25 (n + 1)]];
  num = n - Total[Power[26, #] & /@ (Range[base] - 1)];
  StringJoin@PadLeft[FromCharacterCode /@ (IntegerDigits[num, 26] + 65), base, "A"]]
```

You can condense this into a one-liner without Module of course, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: @Tiger, Thank you for the explanation. it gives me to think

Comment: @Tiger but FromExcelCol[spreadsheetColumn[702]] does not work.

Comment: the correct solution for AAZ = 728 according Excels = COLUMN(AAZ).

Comment: Yep. For me, FromExcelCol["AAZ"] returns 728. Inversely, ToExcelCol[728] returns "AAZ". spreadsheetColumn does not work correctly for me.

This: FromExcelCol /@ ToExcelCol /@ Range[20000] == Range[20000] returns True, so the functions are the correct inverse of each other, empirically.

Comment: @Tiger yes your solution is correct ! COngratulation. The Problem is tricky. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, but anyway I still do not like the code. kale's recursive version is much better in terms of simplicity. However, I am still looking for a good non-iterative (and non-recursive) variant.

Comment: Yes Kale works also fine. Maybe you will find a non interative or non recursive solution. Let me and the community know. thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here's a recursion method:

```
toexcelcolumn[col_?IntegerQ] /; col < 27 := FromCharacterCode[col + 64]
toexcelcolumn[0] = "Z";
toexcelcolumn[col_?IntegerQ] := 
 toexcelcolumn[Quotient[col - 1, 26]] <> toexcelcolumn[Mod[col, 26]]


toexcelcolumn[13935]


(*TOY*)
```

Comment: Also great! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I once developed a function for precisely this problem but I couldn't find at the moment (probably somewhere at the office).

I thought I'd do it this time with a (not-so-elegant) function that takes a bit of preparation, but is much faster once set up. Nice if you have to do numerous look-ups (I once used Mathematica to analyze a 70,000 cell Excel sheet, building a graph of cell relationships. Graphs are a nice visualization tool to study spreadsheets).

```
numToExcel = 
  Dispatch[
    Thread[
      Range[16710] -> 
      DeleteCases[
        (Characters[IntegerString[#, 27]] /. 
           Thread[IntegerString[Range[0, 26], 27] -> {"."}~Join~CharacterRange["A", "Z"]] 
           //StringJoin) & /@ 
       Range[18000], 
       _?(\[Not] StringFreeQ[#, "."] &)]]];
```

What this basically does is building a base **27** set of consecutive numbers, using the "." to represent 0 and A to Z representing 1..26. I then throw away all number strings that contain "." (ugly,  isn't it?), so leaving me with all the consecutive Excel column names. These are then put in a rules `Dispatch` table so that I can say:

```
16384 /. numToExcel
```

> XFD

This is about 7 times faster than Jacob's solution, which on its turn is about 10 times faster than kale's. (I admit this is cheating).

Answer (score 2):

*Sorry for not testing previous versions well. This version works*

I am not sure if I am making things way more complicated than needed. The code below defines the function you want, `spreadsheetColumn`. It is extremely crazy code in which the results of some calculations as well as some coding techniques are densely packed. But the resulting definition will be quite compact and I guess that could be our measure of how simple this solution is.

```
ClearAll[spreadsheetColumn, chR]
(*note that n does not need to be cleared*)

chR = CharacterRange["A", "Z"];

With[
 {numberOfIntegerDigitsPlusOne := Ceiling[Log[26, 26 + 25*n]]
  ,
  numberInTuples := (676 - 26^#)/650 + n}
 ,

 SetDelayed @@ Hold[
   spreadsheetColumn[n_],

   StringJoin@
      Part[chR, 1 + IntegerDigits[numberInTuples - 1, 26, # - 1]] &@
    numberOfIntegerDigitsPlusOne

   ]
 ]
```

examples

```
spreadsheetColumn[26^2 + 4 26 + 3]
```

> "ADC"

```
spreadsheetColumn[27]
```

> "AA"

```
spreadsheetColumn[728]
```

> "AAZ"

**Explanation**

*Warning: There is quite a lot to explain, so I have not filled in all the details (nor have I formatted everything very well)*

Here is a version that is not "packed". It should also work for all bases, not just 26 (although I guess you have to have to have a sensible definition for chR for `base>=26`).

```
n = 26*26 + 26 + 1;
base = 26

numberOfIntegerDigits = Ceiling[Log[base, base - n (1 - base)] - 1];

numberInTuples = n - (base - base^numberOfIntegerDigits)/(1 - base)

(*not so nice, we generate a bunch of useless tuples*)

Tuples[Range[numberOfIntegerDigits], 
  numberOfIntegerDigits][[numberInTuples]]

(*nice alternative*)

charReps = 
  1 + IntegerDigits[numberInTuples - 1, base, numberOfIntegerDigits];

StringJoin@Part[chR, charReps]
```

> "AAA"

**How it works**

We can make 26 columns using one character

We can make 26^2+26 columns using up to two characters

Generalizing this, we can make

```
Sum[26^i, {i, m}}] == (26-26^(m+1))/(1-26) == (26^(m+1)-26)/25
```

columns using n characters.

We can find out how many characters we need to represent our number `n` by finding the largest `m`, `m*`, such that `n >= (26^(m+1)-26)/25`. Let `f[m_]:=(26^(m+1)-26)/25`. Then `m* = Ceiling[(f^-1)[n]]`, where by `^-1` I mean the inverse function (`InverseFunction`). This turns out to be `Ceiling[Log[26, 26 + 25*n]]-1`.

Then we want to subtract  `(26^(m*+1)-26)/25` from our original number, which is the index of our desired combination of characters, in all combinations of m* characters.

I found a nice way to do this last step using `IntegerDigits`, which I guess I was aiming for all along.

**Remark on whether this approach is "too complicated"**

Note that in a usual number system there are base^n numbers represented by up to n numbers. Our characters really correspond to another number system. I am not sure if things can be done much easier for this reason.

*This was kind of a silly exercise, but after all the failed attempts I just had to get a solution :)*

Comment: Try `spreadsheetColumn[702]`. I had I hard time getting this one right.

Comment: Great!!!! Thanks a lot! Walter

Comment: Congratulation, also for finding the bug.

Comment: Indeed, I withdrew my vote as col 26 is incorrectly encoded as AZ

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I think I still like the solution using `IntegerDigits`. However, I think it will a geometric series, strangely. This is turning out to be an interesting problem :) (but also a little frustrating).

Comment: @Jacob: Yes it is not correct, maybe Jacob could find a non recorive solution of this problem with INtegerDigits. That would be great.

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair Well, this is something. I hope somebody likes it :P. Also I am curious if things can be done easier. I always felt like I was so close with my previous versions..

Comment: Jacob, I really like the `Log` part to determine the number of digits in the final column name!

Comment: @TheoTiger thanks! I'm glad you do, I was a bit frustrated with myself.

Comment: @Jacob, thanks a lot. Great done!

Answer (score 1):

Another variant that I wrote here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3905/66

```
integerToLetters[n_]:=
Module[{x},
   x=IntegerDigits[n-1,26];
   x[[;;-2]]-=1;
   StringJoin@@(x/.Thread[Range[0,25]->CharacterRange["A","Z"]])
];
```

Comment: Faysal, please take a look at `Table[integerToLetters[iii], {iii, 500, 800}]`. Can you fix this?

Comment: I tried several similar things. Some of them you can find in the edit history of my answer. But I also tried something where I added one to the last element of "x", like you do. I could not figure it out though, but I am very curious if there is simpler way than my answer. Actually I was frustrated with myself when I saw how simple your answer was. Please don't go through the same frustration in trying to fix this :).

Comment: True it doesn't work for some numbers, at least I know it now, thanks, I'll see if I can correct this, when I can.