# Using the keyboard to interactively and dynamically specify coordinates in a grid (a la Battleship board game)

Tags: dynamic, grid-layouts, interactive

In Mathematica, it is possible to create a `Table` or `Grid` of `\[Placeholder]` boxes.  For example, I can make a 3-by-3 `Grid` of `\[Placeholder]` boxes:

```
Grid[
 Table[\[Placeholder], {3}, {3}],
 Frame -> All, ItemSize -> Full]
```

> [image: Grid]

Then, I can click on one of the placeholders (for example, the top left-hand placeholder) to change focus to it:

> [image: GridFocus]

Once focus is on one of the placeholders, I can use the arrow keys on the keyboard or the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to change the focus to one of the other placeholders (at least in Windows XP; I have not tested this on later versions of Windows or Mac or Linux).

Using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is particularly handy, because it cycles through the placeholders in the "canonical" order (i.e., cells **{1,1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,1}, {2,2}, {2,3}, {3,1}, {3,2}, {3,3}** where the elements are **{row index, column index}**):

[image: GridTab]

But, it can somewhat of a chore to cycle through the placeholders using <kbd>Tab</kbd>, especially for large *n*-by-*n* grids.  My question is, **is it possible to interactively change focus in a grid *using the keyboard*?**

For example, suppose that I label the rows with letters and the columns with numbers:

```
TableForm[
 Table[\[Placeholder], {3}, {3}],
 TableHeadings -> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"1", "2", "3"}}]
```

> [image: GridLabeled]

Is there any way to write a function in which I could type **"b2"**, for example, using the keyboard and have Mathematica automatically change focus to the placeholder at **coordinate b2**, like the following?

> [image: GridLabeledFocus]

With the focus now at **"b2"**, I can mark this coordinate it in some way, perhaps by typing an **"x"**:

> [image: GridLabeledFocusMarked]

Remember [the board game *Battleship*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_%28game%29)?  It is basically a game of placing **"x"** at "hit" coordinates (and placing nothing at "miss" coordinates):

[image: BoardGame]

I would like to use Mathematica to specify and mark coordinates in a grid *interactively, using the keyboard.*  It doesn't matter *how* the coordinates are marked.  In other words, I don't necessarily need the script to change `\[Placeholder]` focus in a `Grid`; I just need to be able to specify coordinates such as **"b2"** interactively (i.e., in real time, not from a list of predefined coordinates) and be able to mark those coordinates in some way.  So, in this sense, it doesn't necessarily need to be a `Grid` of `\[Placeholder]`s.  It could be a `Grid` of `Checkbox`es.  It could be a `Grid` of `Rectangle`s that change color when specified using the keyboard.  In other words, **the important feature I am looking for is to use the keyboard to specify coordinates**, not mouse clicks.

Do you have any initial thoughts of how I can accomplish this?  Do I need to use `Input` or `InputField`, or are there other ways to get keyboard input from the user?  Thanks so much for your time and help.

Comment: Closely [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3868/5478)

Answer (score 5):

**Build in interface**

Undocumented and I don't know how to fully customize it but it seems it is something you're looking for:

```
TableView[RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {10, 10}]]
```

[image]

rubenko deliverd it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3869/5478) with a link to some  info. As Jens have noticed it is not so great but You have to judge it by yourself.

**Custom interface**

If you do not need to have fully editable cells then maybe something like this:

```
n = 9; i = 1; j = 1; grid = Table[\[SelectionPlaceholder], {9}, {9}];
CreateDocument[
  ExpressionCell[
   With[{set = Sequence[ItemSize -> {4, 5}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}]},
    Framed[
     Row[{
       Grid[{{""}~Join~Range@n} // Transpose, set],
       Column[{
         Grid[{CharacterRange["a", "z"][[;; n]]}, set],
    Dynamic@Grid[grid, Background -> Dynamic@{None, None, {i, j} -> Red},
                       set, Frame -> All]
         }]}]]]
   , "Output"]
  ,
  NotebookEventActions -> {
    "UpArrowKeyDown" :> (i = Mod[i - 1, n, 1]),
    "DownArrowKeyDown" :> (i = Mod[i + 1, n, 1]),
    "RightArrowKeyDown" :> (j = Mod[j + 1, n, 1]),
    "LeftArrowKeyDown" :> (j = Mod[j - 1, n, 1]),
    {"KeyDown", "x"} :> (grid = ReplacePart[grid, {i, j} -> "X"]),
    {"KeyDown", "z"} :> (grid = ReplacePart[grid, {i, j} -> "\[CenterDot]"])
    }
  , WindowSize -> {800, 800}
  ]
```

[image]