# How could I make an Excel-like table?

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, grid-layouts

I am looking to build a simple Excel type of a table with four columns.
I have spent some time researching *Mathematica* documentation, but haven't come across a way to implement that.

Here is a picture of what I am aiming to achieve:

1. I'd like to be able to add new rows to this table by specifying
   frequency and probability values
2. I'd like the result to be a product of multiplication of freq. and probability.
3. I'd like to increment index as the new rows are added to the table and decrement when rows are deleted
4. I'd like to be able to remove rows by specifying an index number.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction of where do I begin; e.g., *Mathematica* docs or *Mathematica* SE threads )

I would greatly appreciate any help!

[image: What I am looking to build:]

Comment: you may start here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21122/193

Comment: Just to be clear, you want something that updates dynamically, as a spreadsheet like interface? The following might also be helpful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3868/8

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site! If the questions linked above answer your question, we are likely to close it as a "duplicate". This is not a bad thing: it points people to the right question when they are searching.

Comment: @Verbeia Thank you very much! I really appreciate all your comments with pointers to very valuable sources of information. I will read over the links as soon as I can and get back to leave feedback!