# How to implement a live-searchable table view?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

Everyone with a mobile device is familiar with [table views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html), searchable scrolling tables where rows have multiple elements like images and text, and are populated from some data source. Since a tableview-based app typically has a MVC design (not FP), it makes sense that  I have never seen this done in Mathematica.

**Question:** It looks like there is a built-in function called `TableView[]` but it has no documentation and is rather flakey. Is it exposed for a reason?

There's `ListPicker` as well, but this doesn't support multiple columns. If the output form representation of `DataSet` was malleable and scrollable that could work too. But really a good table view implementation has much more: simple design and templating of the rows, fast text fields searching, smooth scrolling with momentum (>= 60FPS), and dynamic listening to underlying data changes. Are there any known examples of this functionality?

Comment: The fact that there isn't any efficient, documented version of `TableView` is the no. one on my list "why MMA drives me crazy". I mean, it is so natural, people are so used to excel like interfaces, it should be one of priorities. It is so handy to work with. Nvm, here's related topic: [How can I create an advanced grid interface on Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21122/5478)

Comment: Once i needed to view and edit interactively some large data number sets and this [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3868/how-to-visualize-edit-a-big-matrix-as-a-table/)  was very useful ;)

Comment: I ask that you describe the specific characteristics of Table Views that you find *Mathematica* lacks.  For example one can create a scrollable column of values easily with `Pane[Column[Range@50], {Automatic, 200}, Scrollbars -> {False, True}]` -- what does this *lack* that you hope to implement?

Comment: @Kuba: agreed.  Inexplicable gaps like this one is *one* of the reasons that *Mathematica* gets its clocked cleaned (market-share-wise) by overall vastly inferior rivals (e.g. MATLAB).  I wonder if the reason for such gaps is that filling them entails implementing familiar, run-of-the-mill stuff, with little room for mind-blowing, epochal innovation; they just can't work up the enthusiasm for the job.  (Ironically, it's precisely the humdrum, everyday, *thoroughly familiar* stuff that people often miss in *Mathematica*...  Like simple options for specifying ticks, for crying out loud...)